# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not rendering anything on the recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I've checked each and every bit of code in order to successfully render the data on recyclerview from Firebase, but still cannot figure out the problem.

Nothing is show on the logcat when I use Log.d for getting the children of the snapshot(means line is not executed). Can anybody point out the error.

```
public class MyOrders extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MyOrders";
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_orders);

    RecyclerView myOrderList = findViewById(R.id.myOrderList);

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Requests").orderByChild("name").equalTo(User.currentUser.getUserName());

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Request> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>().setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Request>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Request parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+snapshot.getChildrenCount());

            return new Request(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString(), snapshot.child("address").getValue().toString(), snapshot.child("total").getValue().toString());
        }
    }).build();


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, MyOrdersViewHolder>(options){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyOrdersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_order_template, viewGroup, false);
            return new MyOrdersViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyOrdersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Request model) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+position);
            holder.setOrder_id(firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            holder.setOrder_status(model.getOrderStatus());
            holder.setOrder_items(model.getRequestedOrderList().size()+"");
            holder.setItemClickLitener(new ItemClickLitener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v, int pos, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyOrders.this, ""+"Pending Action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    };
    myOrderList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to set a `LayoutManager` on the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: u r a life saver :)